# Is it possible to use any command to create a new repo on github in command line?

Tags: git, github, github-cli

I tried to searched the google but didn't  get any clue about this.
If i can use git command  to create a new repo on github, so i dont have to open github website and click to create a repo,it will be easier to use.

Comment: There is no *Git* command that can create a repository *on GitHub*, but there is a *GitHub* command (`gh`), as in [GMB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72334369/1256452).

Comment: yes.anyway.I want use command to create github repo.It helps alot .Thank u also.I`ll change the question to right .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download [Github CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation)

And use these commands

```
gh repo create [set_name_for_repo]
```